# Can I disable QUERY OPTIMIZATION for MQT in DB2 LUW without recreating it?

Tags: materialized-views, db2-luw

#### UPDATE from 2021

This question is no longer actual for me.

It was a short period when I worked with DB2 and I don't know how it's in recent versions.

The problem was: I could not test effect of MQT without rebuilding it.

Which was not practical when you deal with multi-Gb data.

I did not found solution earlier, I don't know why question was minused.

SO recommends to **not** delete questions with answers and who knows: maybe somebody finally answers that.

---

I have a MQT in DB2 10.5 LUW:

```
CREATE TABLE MyMQT AS(
SELECT * FROM MyTable
    WHERE
        ServerName = 'COL'
        AND LASTOCCURRENCE > TIMESTAMP '2015-12-21 00:00:00' 
)
DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH immediate
ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION
MAINTAINED BY SYSTEM;
```

I want to `DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION` without `DROP/CREATE`.

I found "Altering materialized query table properties" https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.admin/src/tpc/db2z_changemqtableattribs.html
but this is for z/OS.

If I try:

```
ALTER TABLE MyMQT DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

I get:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "TABLE" was found following "ALTER ".  Expected
tokens may include:  "VIEW".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Documentation for LUW explains how to change MQT to regular table and otherwise.

Can I alter MQT options in DB2 LUW without recreating it?

---

#### Edit

It's quite strange, but looks like this is impossible to achieve in DB2 LUW.

As data_henrik mentioned, it's possible to disable/enable optimization for all MQTs.

I accept his answer although it's not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to quickly test queries with and without QUERY REWRITE (oh, sorry, it's an oracle term?). I don't want to wait  several minutes  with drop-create MQT.

Answer (score 0):

No personal experience with it, but you could:

`SET CURRENT MAINTAINED TABLE TYPES FOR OPTIMIZATION = NONE`

This would tell DB2 to not consider any MQT. Later on you would enable query optimization by setting that variable to "system" (the default) or something else. [That statement is documented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007701.html?lang=en).

Comment: Thank you. It's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for? That's how you could disable/enable usage of MQTs.

Comment: Yes. But it disables **all** MQTs. It makes it difficult to use in testing environment and impossible in production.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
refreshable-table-options

|--●--DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED--●--REFRESH--+-DEFERRED--+--●----->
                                           '-IMMEDIATE-'      

   .-ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION--.      
>--+----------------------------+--●---------------------------->
   '-DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION-'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but to any future readers of the question, especially when answering a 5 year old question. Thus, why should I, or anyone else for that matter, "try this"? Instead of adding such a non-sentence to a post, please [edit] it to include an explanation as to **why** this works.